# Передача переменных между файлами

Tags: python-3.x

Есть файл bot.py(главный файл), там есть функция

```
@dp.message_handler(state = ENTRY_ADDRESS)
async def finish_entry(message: types.Message):
    global sum1
    state = dp.current_state(chat=message.chat.id, user=message.from_user.id)
    await state.set_state(None)
    data = await state.get_data()
    sum = data.get('sum')
    address1 = data.get('address1')
    address2 = message.text
    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    result_text = '\n'.join(['UserID: ' + str(message.from_user.id),'Amount: ' + sum,'User address: ' + address2,'Time: ' + str(time)])
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=finish_text, reply_markup=markup)
    await bot.send_message(send_result_id, text=result_text)
```

И есть файл constants. Мне нужно из файла бот в константы передать переменную sum, но когда я в константах пишу from bot import * и запускаю файл бот, то он начинает ругаться, что якобы множество переменных становится неопредленными. Как решить проблему?

Comment: Т.е у меня получается взаимный импорт

Comment: Вы хотите сохранять значения в переменную другого .py файла?

Comment: @gil9red мне нужно в другом файле(вторичном), эту переменную вставить в строку

Comment: `with open('file.txt', 'w') as f: f.write("abc")`?